# Sql View to calculate column based on another column

Tags: sql, database

I have a db views like this:

```
SELECT e.ExportID, e.Date, SUM(t.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM dbo.Exports AS e LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Transactions AS t ON e.TransID = t.TransID
GROUP BY e.ExportID, e.Date, t.Credit
```

Works fine, return the values.

What I need is in the foreach row in transactions, check if the column `t.Credit` is true, if true then add to the TotalAmount, if false then subtract from TotalAmount?

Thanks

Comment: t.Credit == true or will have the integer value ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: you can try: `SUM(IF(t.Credit = 'true', t.Amount, -t.Amount))`  i added explanation to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762720/sql-view-to-calculate-column-based-on-another-column/29763030#29763030

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data type for t.credit is Boolean, you can change your sum to:

```
sum(case when t.credit then t.amount else -t.amount end)
```

Comment: This works great, only one little change on t.Credit = 'true'. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT e.ExportID, e.Date, SUM(IF(t.Credit = 'true', t.Amount, -t.Amount)) AS TotalAmount
FROM dbo.Exports AS e LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Transactions AS t ON e.TransID = t.TransID
GROUP BY e.ExportID, e.Date, t.Credit
```

Because:

```
SELECT IF('true' = 'true', 1, 0);
+---------------------------+
| IF('true' = 'true', 1, 0) |
+---------------------------+
|                         1 |
+---------------------------+
SELECT IF('true' = 'false', 1, 0);
+----------------------------+
| IF('true' = 'false', 1, 0) |
+----------------------------+
|                          0 |
+----------------------------+
```

Justification:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.Credit = 'true', t.Amount, -t.Amount))
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS Amount, 'true' AS Credit
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS Amount, 'false' AS Credit
    UNION
    SELECT 5 AS Amount, 'true' AS Credit
) t;
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| SUM(IF(t.Credit = 'true', t.Amount, -t.Amount)) |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               4 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: @Thunder why this does not provide an answer to the question? Can you tell some arguments?

Comment: Now it looks better ;-)

Comment: @Adrian Cid Almaguer thank you!) i thought that it were explicitly)